# Display Subcategories images on home page

Tags: image, category-tree

I am trying to display my subcategories images on my home page with the following code:

```
<?php
/**
* http://fishpig.co.uk - Magento Tutorials
* Display top level categories and subcategories
**/
$_helper    = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();    
?>
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>

<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>

    <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>


            <div style="float: left; padding-right: 18px; ">    

            <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
            <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
            <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>

                    <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>

                            <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo $_category->getImageUrl() ?>" width="200" height="200" />

                            </a>

                    <?php endforeach; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

But the image shows the parent category instead, can be seen in www.colagenosnella.com.br. Any Thoughts?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to show only the parent level categories or subcategories of a specific category?

Answer (score 0):

Use below foreach loop

```
<?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>


            <div style="float: left; padding-right: 18px; ">    

            <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
            <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
            <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>

                    <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>

                        <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subcategory->getId()) ?>

                            <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo $_category->getImageUrl() ?>" width="200" height="200" />

                            </a>

                    <?php endforeach; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```